# Можно ли по коду (без комментариев) распознать этническую принадлежность?

Tags: обсуждение

*Просто, хочу услышать Ваш опыт или мнение (поэтому задаю на мете)*

Последнее время часто слышу, что-то подобное: "Код написан японцем", причём не "индус-код", а когда люди действительно делают предположения о этнической принадлежности автора.

**Насколько действительно отличаются коды, может правда есть какие-то привычки которые принадлежат определенным этническим группам?** Если Вы замечали что-то подобное было бы очень интересно послушать) Лично я подобного никогда не замечал

Comment: Если код на 1С, то писал скорее всего россиянин любой этнической принадлежности

Comment: @Эникейщик ну здесь да)

Comment: Мета предназначена для обсуждения сайта Stack Overflow, а данный вопрос к таковому не относится и потому подлежит закрытию. (Были попытки разрешить определённый оффтопик на Мете, но, кажется, не взлетело)

Comment: @andreymal хорошо, а где можно задать, вернее в каком формате на этих сайтах?

Answer (score 5):

Скорее всего, в некоторых случаях можно.

Первое, что может броситься в глаза - тексты на родном языке, причём, как в именах переменных, так и в выводимых текстах. Дальше могут быть какие-то переводы. В первую очередь некорректные (в русском "ключ" может означать "родник", но в таком случае перевести как "key" нельзя, ибо в английском такого значения нет), затем наиболее распространённые (в английском есть много синонимов, но англицизмами как правило стали какие-то конкретные из них) и наоборот избегаемые (где-то стараются не использовать слово "task" потому что в их языке оно означает что-то неприличное).

Что касается самого стиля кода, то точно сказать не могу, но я думаю, что специфика должна быть. Хотя все люди и разные сами по себе, но всё же в рамках конкретной группы людей у них есть общие черты и ощиечерты в образе мышления. Я считаю, что это должно влиять на стиль и закладываемую архитектуру, но у меня нет такого опыта работы с иностранцами, чтобы это точно утверждать.

Comment: Когда писал даже не задумывался про названия переменных и правду можно многое сказать, хотя изначально конечно было интереснее про стиль мышления, мне нравится Ваш ответ

Comment: Интересный вопрос и не менее интересный ответ. Возможно `Мета предназначена для обсуждения сайта Stack Overflow, а данный вопрос к таковому не относится и потому подлежит закрытию.`, но поразмышлять было интересно. Плюсую и закрытие вопроса не поддерживаю.

Comment: @Sevastopol' если для вас личные хотелки до сих пор превыше правил, то получается, что вы всё ещё вредитель (и пусть меня забанят за этот комментарий второй раз, но вы всё равно вредитель)